# How to email specific users when a new question is registered

Tags: django, django-views

I would like to send an email to all teachers who teach subjects related to a new question (whether it is created by the admin panel or the question creation form) so that they can approve the question. How to do this?

models.py

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Usuário")
    USUARIO_CHOICES = (
        (UM,'Aluno'),
        (DOIS,'Professor'),
    )
    tipoUsuario = models.IntegerField('Tipo de Usuário',choices=USUARIO_CHOICES,default=1)

class Questao(models.Model):
    aOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True,verbose_name="Letra a")
    bOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True,verbose_name="Letra b")
    cOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True,verbose_name="Letra c")
    dOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True,verbose_name="Letra d")
    eOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True,verbose_name="Letra e")
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'MySite <myemail@outlook.com>'
```

views.py

```
def add_questoes(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = QuestaoForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            form.save()
            subject = 'Questão adicionada'
            message = 'Há uma nova questão adicionada'
            recepient = str(sub['Email'].value())
            send_mail(subject, 
                message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recepient], fail_silently = False)
        return redirect('/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = QuestaoForm() # An unbound form
    return render(request, 'polls/add_question.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class QuestaoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    aOpcao = forms.CharField(max_length=500,label="Letra a")
    bOpcao = forms.CharField(max_length=500,label="Letra b")
    cOpcao= forms.CharField(max_length=500,label="Letra c")
    dOpcao = forms.CharField(max_length=500,label="Letra d")
    eOpcao = forms.CharField(max_length=500,label="Letra e")
    class Meta:
       model = Questao
       fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: you could hook into the question model's post_save signal and handle it accordingly, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/

Django post save signals are a great way to execute code after specific DB operation. In your case I would think you would need to create a post_save signal which triggers the sending of the email.